# Paste timestamp hotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to press a selected hotkey to paste a timestamp in the YYYYMMDDHHmmSS format 20180509145153 immediately, like AutoHotKey allows on Windows.

Comment: What is your operating environment? Linux, NetBSD, Solaris?  And GUI (which?) or text console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it at different levels depending on where you want it to happen. For instance, you could configure your *shell* or prefered *text editor* to  do that, but that would only affect them.

Or you could configure `screen`/`tmux` or your terminal emulator to do it, and it would affect commands running in that terminal emulator when the terminal emulator is the active window.

Under X11, you could use `xbindkey` to handle a specific key or key combination and have it simulate a series of keypress and keyrelease events (using `xte` or `xdotool` for instance). Which would work for any application connecting to the same X server and is active.

For instance, add to your `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"sleep 0.1; xdotool type --clearmodifiers $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
  control+space
```

for that timestamp to be sent as a series of key press upon <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>. (I find that if I don't add the `sleep 0.1`, I'm sometimes missing the start of the timestamp).

Another option would be to store the timestamp as the PRIMARY X11 selection, and simulate a middle mouse button click, which for many application causes the content of the PRIMARY selection to be inserted at the current mouse pointer position. In `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S | tr -d '\n' | xclip; sleep 0.1; exec xdotool click --clearmodifiers 2"
  control+space
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with different scripts in different OS.

## AutoKey in Linux

The [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) [Python](https://www.python.org/) script language is used for the following solution. Tested in my  KUbuntu version 20.04 (based on Ubuntu).

Set the Hotkey in the [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) GUI is self-explanatory (for e.g. Meta+n)

```
# output = system.exec_command("date") # Sa 20. Feb 09:38:39 CET 2021
output = system.exec_command("(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)") # 20210220093839
keyboard.send_keys(output)
```

## AutoHotkey in Linux

You can also use AutoHotkey in Linux (some settings with Wine are necessary).

Here is an example Github solution: https://github.com/sl5net/Lintalist4Linux . Its using the tip's written in https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-wine-5-0-stable-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/