# Eliminate xdotool delay?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xdotool

I have [assigned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442790/270469) the key <kbd>F2</kbd> to the command

```
bash -c "sleep 0.1;xdotool type --clearmodifiers $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
```

There is a delay of half a second (not because of the `sleep 0.1` command that should avoid the first characters to be omitted) before the command starts typing in the timestamp, even if I remove the `sleep 0.1`.

I need to eliminate the delay.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro: Why was the mention of _AutoHotKey_ removed?

Comment: Just simplified the question, it did not bring any added value understanding it. We are in Linux.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I see.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I originally just added it as comparison.

Comment: The delay seems to be part of `xdotool type`. I get it even when running `xdotool type foo`.